# Does Spark structured streaming checkpointing in kafka restart on the correct offset after recovery

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

If I am doing a stateless transformation on a kafka spark structured stream with checkpointing and the application crashes while processing offset x , when the application recovers will it start at the next offset e.g x+1.